# Calling an Object array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I wanted to know the proper way todo a function call of an "Object Array." I'm not sure, my first thought is the scope of the object variable is local to the to function causing the function call error. My second thought is I should have declared the object in main first.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Function Calls
    returnObjectArray();
    scanner();
    userInput(studentInfos,input ); //ERROR HERE is on the function call of Object Array



    }

    public static Object[] returnObjectArray() {

        StudentInfo[] studentInfos = new StudentInfo[2];
        return studentInfos;
    }

    public static Object scanner() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        return input;

    }

    public static Object[] userInput(StudentInfo [] studentInfos, Scanner input) {
        int emplid;
        double quiz1;
          for (int i = 0; i < studentInfos.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter student emplid number");
            studentInfos[i] = new StudentInfo();
            emplid = input.nextInt();
            studentInfos[i].setEmplid(emplid);

            System.out.println("Enter Quiz one percentage");
            quiz1 = input.nextDouble();
            studentInfos[i].setQuizScoreOne(quiz1);

            System.out.println("Enter Quiz two percentage");
            quiz1 = input.nextDouble();
            studentInfos[i].setQuizScoreTwo(quiz1);

            System.out.println("Enter Quiz three percentage");
            quiz1 = input.nextDouble();
            studentInfos[i].setQuizScoreThree(quiz1);
          }

        return studentInfos ;

    }

}
```

Comment: return and lost, so maybe thinking to grab return ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of `StudentInfo[]` declared inside the method, `returnObjectArray` is local to this method. Also, this array will be garbage collected once the method, `returnObjectArray` returns. Similar is the case with the `Scanner` object declared inside the method, `scanner`.

First, replace the following methods as shown below:

```
public static StudentInfo[] returnObjectArray() {
    StudentInfo[] studentInfos = new StudentInfo[2];
    return studentInfos;
}

public static Scanner scanner() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    return input;
}
```

Then, collect the returned values from these methods into variables of respective types and pass them to `userInput` as shown below:

```
StudentInfo[] studentInfos = returnObjectArray();
Scanner input = scanner();
userInput(studentInfos, input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference to the studentInfo[] is not visible outside the method returnObjectArray(); it is a local reference. However, you can create a new reference in the calling (main) method and assign it the return value of the called method.
`StudentInfo[] studentInfos = returnObjectArray();`

Comment: Why is studentInfo[] not visible outside of the method returnObjectArray().

Comment: Because studentInfo is a local variable, imagine it like a bunch of boxes. A big box is the static fields, inside it the instance fields (you have none), then inside of it, are what’s called local variables. That box is the method. Methods cannot reach inside other “boxes” (methods) for variables. In your case, you need to assign the array retuned by returnObjectArray to a local variable inside main, then you can pass it to another method.

Comment: Also, you should use an IDE (IntelliJ is my personal favorite), IDEs will help you fix these problems easier.